# AngularJS UI partially blank/white when scrolling or providing input on mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile

Our angularjs site seems to be having issues with page size on mobile. It seems that when you pull up an input (dropdown or text), some area of the page behind the buttons and inputs goes white.

Regardless of where you are providing input, the white area starts at a particular spot on the page and stretches all the way to the bottom.

I've tried using Safari to inspect the DOM on mobile but I can't seem to figure out where to start debugging this. Any ideas?

On input
[image: On input]

On scroll
[image: On scroll]

Comment: I would look into those main containers for the content to make sure that they dont have a max-height or anything that may be getting forced by the keyboard, it looks like they are getting pushed up to a specific size based on the screen availability and then just allowing for overflow